# Kotlin/Java inheritance and interfaces

Tags: android, inheritance, kotlin, multiple-inheritance, preferencefragment

**Situation:** So i'm building an app using [ncapdevi's FragNav Library](https://github.com/ncapdevi/FragNav) to help me navigate my fragments.

I have have a MainActivity which hosts my three fragments. These three fragments extend `BaseFragment()` (following FragNav app example), which extends `Fragment()`. One of my fragments i want to be a settings page, and i found a tutorial [online here](https://medium.com/@JakobUlbrich/building-a-settings-screen-for-android-part-1-5959aa49337c) that shows how to make a settings page using `PreferenceFragmentCompat`.

**Problem:**  The tutorial's fragment extends `PreferenceFragmentCompat`. Mine extends `BaseFragment`. I'm not really sure how to go about with this, since i know you can only inherit one class in Java/Kotlin.

I did see suggestions about using *Interfaces*, but could maybe someone kind of point me in the correct direction.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to create another `abstract class BasePreference() : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {}` and re-implement or replicate what you have currently at `BaseFragment` for the FragNav Library.

Since `PreferenceFragmentCompat` require you to override `override fun onCreatePreferences(bundle: Bundle, s: String)` and `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_preferences)` you can not disable the preference for other purposes.